# How to extract thin lines as separate contours/connected components with OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I've used the distance tranform thinning on an image. Now trying to extract each connected component separtely - if there are two thin lines, then it should detect three such separate lines and components.

```
/*finding contours*/
IplImage *cc_color; 
cc_color = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(thin_img), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);


    CvMemStorage *mem;
mem = cvCreateMemStorage(0);


int count = 0;
char* ch = new char [2];

CvSeq *contours = 0;

  CvSeq *ptr;
/*finding contours of morphed image*/
cvFindContours(thin_img, mem, &contours, sizeof(CvContour), CV_RETR_CCOMP,       CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

    /*all contours on one image - random coloring*/
for (ptr = contours; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->h_next) 
    {
            CvScalar ext_color = CV_RGB( rand()&255, rand()&255, rand()&255 ); /*randomly coloring different contours*/
            cvDrawContours(cc_color, ptr, ext_color, CV_RGB(0,0,0), -1, CV_FILLED, 8, cvPoint(0,0));          
    }
```

thin_image is the input. the output should have each line colored randomly as a different contour/component. However it's only detecting closed shapes as contours. How do i detect *lines* as components??

Output image: [image: Input image]

Input image: [image]

The red boxes indicate example parts that should be detected as components. But only closed-shapes are detected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the lines/borders as components instead of the inner regions, you should invert the `thin_image` (black -> white and white -> black) before applying `findContours`.

Comment: thank you. it worked this time. Is this the reason for my earlier error - as the thin lines were in black the cvFindContours() was seeing them as _boundaries_ instead of as objects? And after inversion they are considered as objects and not boundaries anymore. I'd like the reasoning to be clear for later development so please explain a bit.

Comment: Yes, black is "boundary" and white is "object".